# default mailto in Chrome PDF cuts emails

Tags: php, email, pdf, google-chrome, mailto

I'm having a problem with the default mailto in Chrome PDF which is cutting the email address.
For example: if my email is "just-me@site.com", when clicking on the email address in the PDF, the email opening will be cut to "me@site.com".

The email on the same PDF opened in Firefox works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that URLs in Chrome need to be escaped with htmlspecialchars in some instances, you might give that a try.